# How to set a variable using dynamic inventory using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, rds

I am looking for method to set a variable in ansible playbook using inventory information received from dynamic inventory.

For example if we have a sample playbook like

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
   - set_fact: rds_hostname="{{ rds_mysql }}" #set rds endpoint from ec2.py

   - debug: var=rds_hostname
```

I am able to get the endpoint when I run the plain ec2.py script as

> "rds_mysql":{
>
> > "rds_mysql.shdahfiahfa.us-easy-1.rds.amazon.com"
> >     }

However I wish to set rds_hostname as the endpoint recieved from dynamic_inventory.

Can any one point out my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my above problem by using something like this

> - set_fact: rds_hostname="{{ groups.rds_mysql[0] }}"

Also during my research I found a nice ansible galaxy code which allows you to dump all variables accessible to ansible-playbooks

https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/646

Hope this helps someone :)